# Why do I need a useless insert statement before a delete statement to prevent a deadlock in this MySQL scenario, and is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, transactions, foreign-keys, deadlock

I have run into a scenario where deleting from and inserting into a table with foreign keys in MySQL is, I believe, causing gap locks to occur that result in a deadlock situation. I am trying to trouble-shoot how to fix this, and the only solution I've come up with is an additional insert before the delete and insert. I was wondering if anyone can explain why these useless inserts are needed and why "select for update" is not similarly locking the rows. I am using MySQL version 5.7.23.

Example schema and initial rows:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE child (
  name VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
  parent INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES parent(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO parent VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO parent VALUES (2);
```

In my code, I need to replace all of the current children for a target parent with a new group of children (zero or more rows), and there may or may not already be children present for this target parent. The current code looks like this, and causes deadlocks when there are no children present in the table for these particular parents:

```
transaction a:
BEGIN WORK;
DELETE FROM child WHERE parent=1;

transaction b:
BEGIN WORK;
DELETE FROM child WHERE parent=2;

transaction a:
INSERT INTO child VALUES ('a', 1);
-- client a hangs waiting for lock

transaction b:
INSERT INTO child VALUES ('b', 2);
-- client b aborts: ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

This will reliably trigger a deadlock if you run these transaction statements in this order in different client sessions. I believe this is because of gap locking. When I attempted to switch the transaction to a READ COMMITTED isolation level, it will avoid the deadlock, but potentially phantom rows will occur if the two transactions are operating on children of the same parent.

Inserting a useless row for the parent prior to the delete appears to fix the deadlock. There is no deadlock in the following scenario:

```
transaction a:
BEGIN WORK;
INSERT INTO child VALUES ('fake', 1);
DELETE FROM child WHERE parent=1;

transaction b:
BEGIN WORK;
INSERT INTO child VALUES ('fake', 2);
DELETE FROM child WHERE parent=2;
-- client b hangs waiting for lock

transaction a:
INSERT INTO child VALUES ('a', 1);
COMMIT;
-- no deadlock; client b now has lock

transaction b:
INSERT INTO child VALUES ('b', 2);
COMMIT;
```

I thought maybe instead of this insert, I could substitute a select statement to get the same locks as the useless insert, but the following does not prevent the deadlock:

```
transaction a:
BEGIN WORK;
SELECT * FROM child WHERE parent=1 FOR UPDATE;
DELETE FROM child WHERE parent=1;

transaction b:
BEGIN WORK;
SELECT * FROM child WHERE parent=2 FOR UPDATE;
DELETE FROM child WHERE parent=2;

transaction a:
INSERT INTO child VALUES ('a', 1);
-- client a hangs waiting for lock

transaction b:
INSERT INTO child VALUES ('b', 2);
-- client b aborts: ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Why do neither the delete nor "select for update" statements retrieve the same lock as inserting a useless row, and is there a better way to accomplish this task and avoid deadlocks? Keep in mind that the child table may or may not have one or more rows already existing for the target parent and I'd like to delete all of the current rows in the child table for the target parent and replace with zero or more new children. Thank you!

Comment: @matigo -- yes, any of these transactions would be finished with COMMIT. The catch is, some of them deadlock and abort before you could ever issue a COMMIT, so I just left all of those off.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. For code questions give a [mre]. (That includes commits & isolation levels for all cases.) PS The deadlock could be relieved or avoided by a commit. It's not clear exactly what the system state is on your deadlock or why you are saying that you have deadlock.

Comment: @philipxy -- If you run the transactions as shown above, one of the clients will hang and the other will abort due to a deadlock and throw an error. The commit isn't even possible to issue. The deadlock happens before you can issue a commit in either session. I have now annotated my question with comments where the deadlocks occur to make it more clear. You can test these in separate clients and run the transaction statements in the order specified to reproduce the deadlocks. The example is reproducible for me, and I took time to refactor the tables into an minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Sure. But it could conceivably make the DBMS lock the whole table instead of just a row or range, an appropriate PK might help. (I don't mean multiple children per parent and/or multiple parents per child, I mean duplicate (name,parent) pairs. That's rarely desired. I'll take your word for it that you might want that.)

Comment: @philipxy -- the real schema is a survey_response_id (parent), a survey's question_id (child, also foreign key in my real schema), and a plain text question_response. Responses can have multiple questions and some questions can have multiple responses. I reduced the schema to reproduce the locking issue above. Is the useless INSERT just locking the entire table and that's why it's working with the useless insert, but not in the other scenarios?

Comment: what is the isolation level you are using you should use `serializable` or else add an index on the `parent` column. If you are still getting the error you can `innodb_status_output_locks=ON` and then you can check for logs for detail lock status.

Answer (score 1):

Without a `PRIMARY KEY` on `Child`, most actions need to do a full table scan.

In any case, your code must plan for deadlocks, even if you might be able to avoid most deadlocks.

In general, the way to handle deadlocks is to test for such after each SQL statement.  When one occurs, start over the transaction.  (It is likely that the second attempt will avoid other connections that helped cause it.)

Note that this means that transactions should be coded to be "short".  The longer a transaction is, the more other connections might be blocked.

Comment: Why isn't it enough to have the foreign key index on parent column since these transactions are operating on different parent values? It seems like MySQL should be able to just lock those rows that are associated with the parent. Is there a better way to structure this if I can't have a primary key on child? There could be duplicate children for a parent. Do I need to lock the entire table at the start of the transaction to prevent a deadlock in the case where I want to replace multiple child rows, or is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: @Matt - Why "can't you have a primary key"?

Comment: There may be multiple rows in the child table that contain the same (parent, name) values, so the "name" column will not be unique. I presume you were suggesting a primary key on the "name" column, but if instead you meant adding an 'id' column to the 'child' table that is a primary key, that results in the same deadlock for me.

Comment: @Matt - Would this work?  `PRIMARY KEY(parent, name), INDEX(name)` -- That is, the _pair_ (parent,name) is unique without either one being unique.

Comment: @Matt You don't seem to know what a PK is. Also your comments in reply to my comments re entire rows being duplicated don't address entire rows being duplicated.

Comment: Hi @RickJames -- I just tried your suggested primary key and index defined during table creation, and I receive the same deadlock during insertion as noted in this question. The primary key does not prevent the deadlock shown in the first code example if you run those two transactions in different sessions simultaneously.

Comment: Hi @philipxy -- Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I do know what a primary key is and I am looking to avoid one combined on the four columns it would take in my actual table to guarantee uniqueness (one of which is a TEXT column). As I also just tested, in my stripped down example even a primary key on (parent, name) does not prevent the deadlock shown in my example.

Comment: @Matt - What happens if your test involves parents 1 and 3?  But also have a row with parent=2 in the table all the time.  I ask because there is such a thing as "gap locking".  When you delete both 1 and 2, they are in the same "gap".  But if a "2" row is sitting between 1 and 3, they are not in the same gap.

Comment: Hi @RickJames, If child table is empty, this still deadlocks. If there are rows in child table for all three parents prior to the transactions, then no deadlock. So I agree it is likely gap locking that is causing this, and I did mention in my original question that it is my suspicion. However, the way these requests come in for my database, these transactions will often be for newly created parents (which means the highest two parent ids), both of which will not yet have entries in child table, so gap-lock deadlocks are likely. I'm curious if there is a way to avoid this.

Comment: @Matt - It is probably impossible to prevent all deadlocks, so, see the text I added to my answer.  It discusses what should be done in any multi-connection application.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. The application is actually robust against most deadlocks by doing things like accessing tables in the same order across different transactions, etc. Even in this scenario, I can prevent the deadlock with a useless insert as noted in the original post. I was mostly curious if there was a better way, and why select for update won't get me the same lock as the useless insert. I wonder if there is no way to grab that gap lock other than the useless insert?

Comment: @Matt - Look at it this way...  The cost of a spurious extra query inside the transaction adds up to more than the rare need to replay the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There two things. First of all, you should definitely define a primary key for the child table. When there is not one, MySQL is trying to identify a field that can be used for indexing and if not found, an internal one will be generated. This will cause overhead and is just a bad habit. More on this for example in here https://vettabase.com/blog/why-tables-need-a-primary-key-in-mariadb-and-mysql/.

Second, and the most important thing is, why are you using two transactions? If you are about to edit the same table and to do both operations as an atomic transaction, do then inside of one commit:

```sql
BEGIN WORK;

DELETE FROM child WHERE parent=1;
DELETE FROM child WHERE parent=2;

INSERT INTO child VALUES ('a', 1);

INSERT INTO child VALUES ('b', 2);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hi Ville -- thank you. I do have an index defined on the table (the parent foreign key designation will create an index, although not a unique index). I do not have a primary key, but even adding one on (parent, name) in the child table does not prevent the deadlock. Also, I am using two transactions because these are different requests coming into a web application from different people that result in the deadlock. So I am simulating those two transactions running side by side, as can happen if two different requests to operate on the children of different parents come in simultaneously.

Comment: Have you tried to add the primary key? It is just a theory, but one possible reason for the behavior is that the database desired to execute the full table scan on your delete which will lock the whole table. This would end up naturally to the symptoms you are describing.

Comment: Hi Ville -- yes, I tried adding the primary key but deadlock still exists. You can read more in the comments to the other proposed answer. I believe it is due to gap locking.